# Use MYSQL UNIQUE INDEX and INDEX

Tags: mysql, unique-key

I have a MYSQL table with a column that must accept only unique values, so I added a UNIQUE key to the column to enforce uniqueness.

I run a query with LIKE operator on the column and I read that it's recommended to have an INDEX on the column for the query to perform well. Is the UNIQUE INDEX I currently have enough as an index or I should add a regular index as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unique index on a column is an index on that column that also enforces the constraint that you cannot have two equal values in that column in two different rows. So no, you do not need another index.